# With Microsoft's WebAPI, is it possible to have multiple POST methods in one controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I notice that the method created by the scaffolding is called POST and that there are not [HttpPost] attributes on it.  If I want to create multiple POST methods, like in my case I want to have a controller named "Register" and I want to have one method called "RegisterAttendee" and another called "RegisterSpeaker".  I want them to have different protection levels so I want two different method calls.

Is that possible with WebAPI like plane old MVC controllers with the [HttpPost] attribute?

Comment: It would seem to me that this is related to how you set up your routes more than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can define multiple posts in a controller with [httppost] attribute. However you only need to use that attribute when your method name doesnt start with Post. You can differentiate between different Post calls by different number of parameters and/or by defining routes in your config.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm. is there anything  necessary beyond the default route to make them work?  I tried to add another method, just used the catch all Form Collection parameter, and I keep getting no access.  The Post method worked straight away.  I did not realize it just need to start with the word Post. that is a help.

Comment: after investigating further, it seems that my error was not a 403 but a duplicate controller methods found. It was because I had the POST default method there and that seems to always be available as a duplicate for some reason.  I still don't get the default router logic.

Comment: Adding a Route other than default depends on your scenario. If you follow the POST as a result of scaffold. There is no need for you to change. Another thing that you can do here .  You can also create another controller and use the POST method there. In this case you can control that POST through the routing. I hope you get what i am trying to say here.

Comment: @PeterKellner as i mentioned earlier . You can play with different paramters. For example. If you add another parameter in your custom POST method. and pass it from query string . The router should not be confused and properly directed.